# Trying to uninstall elasticsearch results error

Tags: elasticsearch

sudo apt-get remove elasticsearch results to

E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/elasticsearch-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: run: dpkg -l |grep elasticsearch . do you have elasticsearch package installed? try apt-get -f install then apt-get --purge elasticsearch

Comment: or apt-get autoremove elasticsearch. before that be sure there is no service elasticsearch is running and all process killed.

Comment: Thanks for help.No, I don't have installed Elasticsearch, and I have tried running all the cmd given by you but still I am getting the same error. Please help me with this situation.

Comment: I was trying to install elasticsearch 5.4 using this link https://www.willandskill.se/en/articles/install-elasticsearch-5-x-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-in-less-than-3-minutes but in between got this error.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

   you can see your all `.list` files like

   > elastic-5.x.list
   > elastic-8.x.list
   > google-chrome.list
   > obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-jammy.list
   > sublime-text.list~
   > teamviewer.list

   choose the one of them that has problem and remove it using the following command
2. `sudo rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-5.x.list`
3. `sudo apt remove -f elasticsearch`